# How to change the css style with a html inline link

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page with a lot of boxes which have inline html links inside of them so the user can get to them quickly. Here's my question:

Is it possible with the use of jquery that when you click the link mysite.com/test/#box1 the respective box to change its style (example - add a red border around box1 so the user quickly sees it) or not? How could I accomplish something like this?

**HTML**:

```
<div class="box1">
  <a name="box1"></a>
  ...content1...
</div>
<div class="box2">
  <a name="box2"></a>
  ...content2...
</div>
<div class="box3">
  <a name="box3"></a>
  ...content3...
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What's your next question?

Comment: My next question would be how to do it

Comment: You're generally supposed to try something yourself, then post a question that explains where you're stuck. Your question simply amounts to "please do the work for me".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
.border {
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```
$('a').click(function() {
   e.preventDefault()
   $(this).closest('div').addClass('border')
})
```

or:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var h = document.location.hash.replace('#', '')
   $('.'+h).addClass('border')
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do through css3 as well!

```
<div id="boxDiv1">
    <a name="box1" href="#boxDiv1" >Test Link</a>
</div>

<style>
#boxDiv1:target { border:1px solid red; }
</style>
```

You can do this for anchor as well

Comment: +1. Although you should have a note in there stating how cross-browser this is. For instance, I know it doesn't work in IE. In these cases a JS fallback is a better option.

Comment: Yes you are right but hitting url like this mysite.com/test/#box1 will also work.

Comment: yes it will, not doubting that, but only in some browsers/versions of browsers. All I say is that it would make a better answer WITH those versions included as well. I could simply do a search and find how cross-browser it is, but including that info in your answer will make it better. :)